# Server side chart .svg export with Highcharts and PhantomJS, error loading data from .csv file

Tags: csv, highcharts, export, server-side, phantomjs

I’ve been trying to develop a server side picture export (.svg) of a chart (using Highcharts library) solution based on a chapter in Pact publishing book “Learning Highcharts” – chapter:“Running Highcharts on the Server Side”. The example in the book uses HighchartExport.js script and data stored in seriesData.js file and PhantomJS, a headless webkit. I find it “normal” to export data from DB in formats like .csv or xml or json so I made a chart based on http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing-data-from-a-file-csv-xml-json. The chart works just fine when being executed in a normal browser – server environment, but when I rewrite it for PhantomJS, something goes wrong. The PhantomJS script code I’m using is as follows:

```
/*
This is HighchartsExportSO.js  
phantomJS Script for Highcharts chart 
(data in file test.csv)
*/

var system = require('system');
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');

page.onError = function (msg, trace) {
    console.log(msg);
    trace.forEach(function(item) {
        console.log('  ', item.file, ':', item.line);
    })
}

/*Callback to enable messages from inside page evaluate function*/
page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg) {
    console.log('Page says: ' + msg);
};

page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, networkRequest) {
    console.log('Request (#' + requestData.id + '): ' + JSON.stringify(requestData));
};

page.onResourceReceived = function(response) {
    console.log('Response (#' + response.id + ', stage "' + response.stage + '"): ' + JSON.stringify(response));
};

page.onResourceError = function(resourceError) {
    console.log('Unable to load resource (#' + resourceError.id + 'URL:' + resourceError.url + ')');
    console.log('Error code: ' + resourceError.errorCode + '. Description: ' + resourceError.errorString);
};

page.injectJs("jquery-1.10.2.min.js");
page.injectJs("highcharts.js");
page.injectJs("exporting.js");

// Load width and height from parameters
var width = parseInt(system.args[2], 10) || 1366;
var height = parseInt(system.args[3], 10) || 768;

// Build up result and chart size args for evaluate function
var evalArg = {
width: width,
height: height
};

// The page.evaluate method takes on a function and
// executes it in the context of page object.
var svg = page.evaluate(function(opt) {
    $('body').append('<div id="container"/>');
    /*Setting chart options*/
    var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Chart Name
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    labels: {
                        step: 10,
                        rotation: -45,
                        style: {
                            fontSize: '9px',
                            fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                        }
                    },
                    categories: []
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: '% Percentage'
                    }
                },
                series: []
            };

    //Loading data from csv file    
    $.get('test.csv', function(data) {
                // Split the lines
                var lines = data.split('\n');           
                // Iterate over the lines and add categories or series
                $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
                    var items = line.split(',');            
                    // header line containes categories
                    if (lineNo == 0) {
                        $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                            if (itemNo > 0) options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
                        });
                    }               
                    // the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first position
                    else {
                        var series = {
                            data: []
                        };
                        $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                            if (itemNo == 0) {
                                series.name = item;
                            } else {
                                series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
                            }
                        });
                        options.series.push(series);
                    }
                });
    });
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    return chart.getSVG();
}, evalArg);
if (fs.isFile("chart.svg")) {
fs.remove("chart.svg");
}
fs.write("chart.svg", svg);
phantom.exit();
```

So, when I execute  “phantomjs.exe HighchartsExportSO.js” in cmd, I don't get any errors, and actual .svg file is being generated, but without data series in it, which brings me to believe that something is wrong with the $get function. My question is why doesn’t that work in PhantomJS and what must I do to get it to work.
(Btw, I’m working in Win7 environment and PhantomJS version is 1.9.2)
The example data file (test.csv) would contain following data:

```
Dates,01-JUL-13,02-JUL-13,03-JUL-13,04-JUL-13,05-JUL-13,06-JUL-13,07-JUL-13
Series1,74.57,76.91,84.35,85.3,86.25,89.31,89.73
Series2,100,99.99,99.99,99.99,99.99,99.99,99.99
Series3,97.09,99.8,99.85,99.9,99.91,99.92,99.94
```

Answer (score 0):

The $.get function is out of place here. JQuery $.get loads data from the server using a GET request. Instead you need a plain file read.

An example how you could do this.

```
// read the csv file
var data = fs.read('test.csv');

var svg = page.evaluate(function(opt, data) {
    ...
    var lines = data.split('\n');
    // Iterate over the lines and add categories or series
    $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
       ...
    });
},evalArg, data);
```

Comment: Just a side note, you're not using the 'opt' variable in your script.